# Кто может помочь с JUnit тестированием легкой программки?

Tags: java, junit

```
public class Matrix_Multiplication {
Scanner scan;
int matrix1[][], matrix2[][], multi[][];
int row, column;

void create() 
{
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Matrix Multiplication");

    // First Matrix Creation..

    System.out.println("\nEnter number of rows & columns");
row = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
column = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
matrix1 = new int[row][column];
matrix2 = new int[row][column];
multi = new int[row][column];
    System.out.println("Enter the data for first matrix :");
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
    matrix1[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
}   

    // Second Matrix Creation..

System.out.println("Enter the data for second matrix :");
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
    matrix2[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
}
}

void display() 
{
    System.out.println("\nThe First Matrix is :");
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
    System.out.print("\t" + matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println("\n\nThe Second Matrix is :");
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
    System.out.print("\t" + matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    System.out.println();
}
}

void multi() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
    multi[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[i][j];
        }
}
    System.out.println("\n\nThe Multiplication is :");
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
        {
            System.out.print("\t" + multi[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
}
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день,

Такой код действительно очень сложно протестировать:)
Есть предложение сделать методы болeе общими и выделить параметры от которых они зависят в аргументы, а результаты алгоритма в возвращаемые значения.
Так же пытайтесь избегать дублирования кода.

Например:

```
public class Matrix_Multiplication {
Scanner scan;

public Matrix_Multiplication() {
    scan =  new Scanner(System.in);
}

public int askForInt(String message){
    System.out.println(message);
    return Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
}


public int[][] createMatrix(int rows, int columns) {
    int matrix[][] = new int[rows][columns];
    System.out.println("Enter the data for matrix :");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

public void display(int[][] matrix) {
    System.out.println("\nMatrix is :");
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public int[][] multi(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2) {
    int row = matrix1.length;
    int column = matrix1[0].length;
    int result[][] = new int[row][column];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            result[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
   return result;
}

public void closeResourses(){
    scan.close();
}
}
```

Тогда main будет примерно таким:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix_Multiplication matrixMultiplication = new Matrix_Multiplication();
    int rows = matrixMultiplication.askForInt("\nEnter number of rows");
    int columns = matrixMultiplication.askForInt("\nEnter number of columns");

    int[][] matrix1 = matrixMultiplication.createMatrix(rows, columns);
    int[][] matrix2 = matrixMultiplication.createMatrix(rows, columns);

    int[][] result = matrixMultiplication.multi(matrix1, matrix2);

    matrixMultiplication.display(result);
    matrixMultiplication.closeResourses();

}
```

и тесты написать будет намного проще, достаточно вызвать метод с параметрами и сравнить с ожидаемым результатом:

```
 @Test
public void testMultiiple() {
    int[][] m1 = new int[][]{
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };
    int[][] m2 = new int[][]{
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    int[][] expectedResult = new int[][]{
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };
   assertArrayEquals(expectedResult,matrix_multiplication.multi(m1,m2));

}
```